# If checbox/disable element not working properly

Tags: javascript, if-statement, disabled-input

I'm attempting to make a script so that if you check/uncheck a checkbox input, that it will enable/disable a target input text box. My code if statement doesn't seem to function correctly sometimes firing both ifs at once, other times not firing at all. I've done debugging and tried numerous variations but it still won't work. Here is what I have, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function disable(elem) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(elem);
    status = obj.disabled;
    console.log(status);
    if (status = true) {
        console.log("test");
        obj.disabled = false;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    if (status = false) {
        console.log("test2");
        obj.disabled = true;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "bfbfbf";
    }
}
```

Comment: And you're sure an assignment operator should be used in condition expressions? Also, you should declare `status` too, it being a global variable might lead to troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not exhibiting proper behavior for several reasons.

The first reason is that your if statements are inline, not in an if-else form. A better organization is as follows:

```
function disable(elem) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(elem);
    status = obj.disabled;
    console.log(status);
    if (status == true) {
        console.log("test");
        obj.disabled = false;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    } else {
        console.log("test2");
        obj.disabled = true;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "#bfbfbf";
    }
}
```

This means that even if the variable you are checking changes while the code in the block is executing, it will not execute the code in the opposing block regardless of its new value. As you have it, if the value were to change while the code in the first if statement was running, then it is possible for both control blocks to run.

The second reason it is not behaving right is due to the incorrect syntax within your if statement. You are currently using the `=` operator which means set the variable to what you are wanting to check against. You must use either the `==` or `===` equality checks (the latter is type strict) if you want to write them this way. An even better way is to omit that operator entirely by just checking if the value is truthy, like so:

```
function disable(elem) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(elem);
    status = obj.disabled;
    console.log(status);
    if (status) {
        console.log("test");
        obj.disabled = false;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    } else {
        console.log("test2");
        obj.disabled = true;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "#bfbfbf";
    }
}
```

This should give you your expected control behavior :) As was mentioned, make sure you are formatting your values appropriately (e.g. "#bfbfbf" not "bfbfbf")

Comment: `obj.style.backgroundColor = "bfbfbf";` also needs a `#` like `#bfbfbf`

Comment: good point. I only looked at the control statements themselves. I'll fix this for him as well

Comment: interesting that the color thing worked just fine but yes the boolean operator `==` fixed my issue, along with your organizational adjustments. Thank you so much

Comment: How can the variable change while the code is executing? Javascript is single-threaded. I agree with using `if/else`, because it's more understandable, but it shouldn't fix a problem like this.

Comment: if he sets it within the code block of course :) It is not uncommon to see a boolean switch like that used.

Comment: This question should just be closed as a typo, because of the `=` vs. `==` mistake.